# Kann man »ebnen« substantivieren?

Tags: grammaticality, nominalization

Ist jemand, der einen Weg ebnet, ein *„Wegebner“*? Kann man das grammatikalisch korrekt sagen?

Comment: Früher bekam der, der in der Ebene *wohnte*, den Nachnamen "Ebner" (im Gegensatz zu dem, der auf dem Berg wohnte, der hieß dann "Berger") - Das ist immernoch einigermaßen im "Sprachgedächtnis" eingebaut und daher mißverständlich.

Comment: @tofro: Das ist aber lokaler Gebrauch, oder? (Süddeutsch?)

Comment: @dirkt Würde ich vermuten,  ja. Würde aber auch gefühlsmäßig vermuten, dass "eben" eher süddeutschen Ursprungs ist. "Ebner" ist i.Ü. ein ziemlich häufiger Nachname.

Comment: @tofro: Ich kenne Berger (von Senta Berger, aber niemanden persönlich, der so heißt), aber habe Ebner noch nie bewusst registriert. Was nicht heißt, dass es sie hier nicht gibt, aber häufig kann es nicht sein. Raum Frankfurt/Main.

Comment: Ebner ist nicht so häufig wie Müller, aber an der schweizer Grenze sehr verbreitet.

Comment: Keine Ahnung wie zuverlässig die Daten sind, aber hier erkennt man eine Häufung im südöstlichen Bayerischen Wald und wie @tofro sagte an der Grenze zur Schweiz: http://www.verwandt.de/karten/relativ/ebner.html

Comment: Ein *Bauarbeiter*? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Üblicher wird wohl der "Wegbereiter" sein. "Der Wegebner" ist sicherlich nicht falsch, aber etwas ungewöhnlich und hakelig beim Lesen.

Answer (score 4):

Als Ersatz für das unübliche *»Wegebner«* sind neben dem schon genannten *»Wegbereiter«* auch

> - [Vorreiter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorreiter)
> - [Vordenker](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vordenker)
> - [Pionier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pionier)

gebräuchlich.

Comment: Vielleicht auch: Pfadfinder?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich kenne Pfadfinder nur als die Jugendgruppe. In der Bedeutung von "Wegbereiter" ist mir das Wort noch nie untergekommen. Auch der Duden kennt nur die eine Bedeutung.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: *»Pfadfinder«*, wörtlich genommen, geht schon in die richtige Richtung, wird nur nicht (mehr?) so verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Es kommt darauf an, **wo** du so etwas schreibst.

Es gibt Textgattungen, die eine Wortwahl aus dem Standardrepertoire der Sprache erfordern wie z.B. behördliche Schreiben oder technische Betriebsanleitungen oder Nachrichtentexte in der Zeitung.

Andere Textgattungen rufen danach, kreativ mit dem Wortschatz umzugehen (Gedichte, Glossen in der Zeitung, launige Forenbeiträge...), und folglich sind auch seltene Wörter oder gar Neuschöpfungen dort gern gesehen.

Dein "Wegebner" wäre sicherlich etwas für die zweite Gruppe.

---

Persönliche Anschlussnote: Je länger ich mir deinen *Wegebner* im Hirn zergehen lasse, desto mehr gewöhne ich mich daran, und da das Wort so kurz ist und aus derart standardrepertoiremäßigen Teilen besteht, habe ich nun schon fast das Gefühl, es sei ein etablierters Wort, das auch der städtische Verwaltungssachbearbeiter verwenden dürfte...